# Update values with brackets in a dictionary

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to replace values in a dictionary using a for loop. But this is a bit special cause it has values inside the brackets.

My question is: **How to update values that are inside the bracket for a dictionary?**

Need to

1. Update the `n_estimator` accordingly.
2. Update the classifer accordingly using Models (e.g. `BaggingClassifier` and `RandomForestClassifier`).

**Initialization**

```
n_estimator = [5, 10, 20]

models = {'Bagging': BaggingClassifier(random_state=12345),
          'RandomForest': RandomForestClassifier(random_state=12345)
         }
```

**Loop**

```
for x in list(models):
    for y in n_estimator:
       models[x] = x + Classifier(random_state=12345, n_estimators=y); 
    print(x)
```

**Current Results**

```
Bagging
RandomForest

BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=None, bootstrap=True,
         bootstrap_features=False, max_features=1.0, max_samples=1.0,
         n_estimators=10, n_jobs=1, oob_score=False, random_state=12345,
         verbose=0, warm_start=False)
```

Seems like I'm doing it wrongly as I'm adding a new one instead of updating the current values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you can get rid of the dictionary altogether. Here's a possible way to create instances of different classifiers with different parameters:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier, BaggingClassifier

for model in [RandomForestClassifier, BaggingClassifier]:
    for n in [5, 10, 20]:
        clf = model(random_state=12345, n_estimators=n)
        print(clf)
```

The code above yields:

```
RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, class_weight=None, criterion='gini',
            max_depth=None, max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None,
            min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
            min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
            min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=5, n_jobs=1,
            oob_score=False, random_state=12345, verbose=0,
            warm_start=False)
RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, class_weight=None, criterion='gini',
            max_depth=None, max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None,
            min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
            min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
            min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=10, n_jobs=1,
            oob_score=False, random_state=12345, verbose=0,
            warm_start=False)
RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, class_weight=None, criterion='gini',
            max_depth=None, max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None,
            min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
            min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
            min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=20, n_jobs=1,
            oob_score=False, random_state=12345, verbose=0,
            warm_start=False)
BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=None, bootstrap=True,
         bootstrap_features=False, max_features=1.0, max_samples=1.0,
         n_estimators=5, n_jobs=1, oob_score=False, random_state=12345,
         verbose=0, warm_start=False)
BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=None, bootstrap=True,
         bootstrap_features=False, max_features=1.0, max_samples=1.0,
         n_estimators=10, n_jobs=1, oob_score=False, random_state=12345,
         verbose=0, warm_start=False)
BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=None, bootstrap=True,
         bootstrap_features=False, max_features=1.0, max_samples=1.0,
         n_estimators=20, n_jobs=1, oob_score=False, random_state=12345,
         verbose=0, warm_start=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems you appending the new values. for updating you have to assign value with array indexed